# Check if file exist if true then open SFTP

Tags: sftp, file-exists

First time using this website, i have a challenge now with one of our clients that they are blocking our SFTP account if we connect and do not send any file.
Something that i am looking for is a script for powershell or could be anything that i can build into .exe file with visual studio so that the script firstly would check:

Check if file exists
If False then stop
If true open sftp and send the file

any help would be trully appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try-except block to figure out if the file is open

```
try:
    file = open("Your file's location",'r')
except:
    pass
else:
    # Everything else goes here #
    file.close()
```

Comment: What i found usefull is: 
test-path FILEPATHt\*.txt

Then i use if else but now im a bit strugling on SFTP script for powershell.. on simple ftp it was rather easy "open ftp.blablabla.com"

Not working on sftp this properly.. :(

Comment: Try updating your question to give me as much information as possible